# Api to remove indentation for multiple files

Tags: python-2.7

I have 7000 cpp files with me which i want to convert into images. I want to remove the indentation of each file. Manually doing it using shift+tab is very exhaustive. Is there a way to do it using any script file or api. I am using python version 2.7.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

The below program will remove all the whitespace in a given file line by line:

```
with open("filename", 'w') as f:
for line in f:
    line.strip()
f.write("filename')
```